# Why does the root element in my App.vue template have to match the one in index.html?

Tags: vue.js

I have created a project using the vue cli (version 3.0.0-rc.10) and configured it to use typescript.

In the index.html file it creates, there is a `<div id="app"></div>` which if I understand correctly the main.ts file will look for via the mount function in the below code

```
new Vue({
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

However, when I look in the App.vue files  it also has a root element of div with an id of app.

Why must the App.vue’s template have a div exactly the same as that found in index.html?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't have to have `id="app"` in the `App.vue` file, change the ID to whatever you want.

`$mount('#app')` replaces the existing `<div id="app">` from the `index.html` not from the `App.vue`. It's just boilerplate code.

Comment: Do you know any reason? It's kinda hard to find out for a beginner.